# unknown device Dell e6530

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

I would like to find driver for a device, identified by the following hardware ID:

```
ven_8086&dev_1e3a&subsys_05351028&REV_04
```

In an Internet discussion I found that is PCI communication controller which is a modem. I tried to search on Dell website by service tag, but I couldn't find anything related.

The operating system is freshly installed. Windows 7 32-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Quick analysis

The Vendor ID is `8086`, which is assigned to [Intel Corp.](http://www.pcidatabase.com/vendor_details.php?id=1302) The Device ID is `1e3a`, and is related to the **Intel Management Engine Interface (MEI)**.

> The Intel Management Engine (Intel ME) is an isolated and protected computing
>   resource (Co-processor) residing inside certain Intel chipsets. The Intel ME
>   provides support for computer/IT management features. The feature set
>   depends on the Intel chipset SKU.
>
> The Intel Management Engine Interface (Intel MEI, previously known as HECI)
>   is the interface between the Host and Intel ME. This interface is exposed
>   to the host as a PCI device. The Intel MEI Driver is in charge of the
>   communication channel between a host application and the Intel ME feature.
>
> <sub>Source: [MEI in the Linux kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/misc-devices/mei/mei.txt)</sub>

You can find the driver in the official [Dell support page](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/Product/latitude-e6530) under the **Chipset** category.

Comment: which of ten items is Intel Management Interface?

Comment: @Jerry1 The actual driver is labeled **Intel(R) Management Engine Components Installer**. That's the most updated version. There's also another driver available called **Intel Management Engine 8.x Components Installer Driver** which you might try in case the other one doesn't work properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, first advice (Intel(R) Management Engine Components Installer) works!