# Unknown PCI device in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, pci

Does anyone know what device could this be?

[image]

I got all drivers for my computer from [here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag/G4NKG12/drivers)

Comment: Double-click it, go to *Details*, choose *Hardware Ids* from the list and post first line that appears (you can `Ctrl+C` it)

Comment: did you installed all the chipset drivers?

Comment: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9C24&SUBSYS_05E01028&REV_04
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9C24&SUBSYS_05E01028
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9C24&CC_118000
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9C24&CC_1180

Comment: I think so yes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have "unknown PCI device" in Windows 7 device manager. What can it be?](http://superuser.com/questions/657879/i-have-unknown-pci-device-in-windows-7-device-manager-what-can-it-be), [unknown device Dell e6530](http://superuser.com/questions/734755/unknown-device-dell-e6530)

Comment: The device appear to be related with [Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework (DPTF)](https://01.org/intel%C2%AE-dyanmic-platform-and-thermal-framework-dptf-chromium/overview). Try installing the following driver: http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/driverdetails?driverid=0NCMH

Answer (score 0):

The device driver (in fact it's no "unknown device"!) you are looking for is:

Intel® Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Driver